# Working with 3 tables in a Laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a season, and each clan has to have a valid season entry. The stage I'm currently stuck on is how can I have a relationship for clans in my Season class?

This would help me understand which clans a season currently holds, but without a complicated query, it seems impossible with relationships. Is there a 'good practice' way of doing this?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Season extends Model
{
    public function matches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClanMatch', 'season_id');
    }

    public function tournaments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tournament', 'season_id');
    }
}

class SeasonEntry extends Model
{
    public function season() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Season', 'season_id');
    }

    public function clan() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Clan', 'clan_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention whats wrong in your code.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong, I'm asking how to implement functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Think if simple.

- One clan can participate in many seasons.
- One seasons, there are many clans.

So I guess, this is `Many-to-Many` relationship. To deal with it in Laravel, commonly, you need to create a pivot table that defines the co-relation.

```
    Schema::create('season_clan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('season_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('clan_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

And both models need to address the relationship as well.

```
class Season extends Model
{
    public function clans()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clan::class);
    }
}

class Clan extends Model
{
    public function seasons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Seasons::class);
    }
}
```

That's all I guess! You can try and it should work.

Comment: Huge thanks to you, I'm about to test it. Quick question, this might be pretty obvious but do I migrate that migration? (create the table in the DB) or is it just to help Laravel undersand?

Comment: You need to create that pivot table to map many-to-many relationship. It's almost the same in any ORM, not only Laravel.

Comment: One issue with your code, when migrating I receive `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'CreateSeasonClanTable' not found`. Any idea?

Comment: Spending 5 mins to learn basic Laravel migrations https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations will save you a lot of time in future

Comment: `php artisan make:migration create_season_clan_table` to create migration file, add the above schema `up()`, make sure to provide a `down()` to rollback.

Comment: I've tested the code and it seems to return an empty collection (0) when calling `dd(Season::find(1)->clans()->count());`, season exists, clan exists, as well as the record in session_entries table. Calling `clans` not `clans()` is the same.

Comment: Also, your pivot is called season_clan, using that gave me `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bo4.clan_season' doesn't exist (SQL: select `clans`.*, `clan_season`.`season_id` as `pivot_season_id`, `clan_season`.`clan_id` as `pivot_clan_id` from `clans` inner join `clan_season` on `clans`.`id` = `clan_season`.`clan_id` where `clan_season`.`season_id` = 1)`, after changing it to `clan_season` it resulted in an empty collection.